# Exception starting filter struts2

Tags: struts2

Exception starting filter struts2

```
Unable to load configuration. - [unknown location]
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:431)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.init(FilterDispatcher.java:190)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4072)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4726)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.checkResources(HostConfig.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1382)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:306)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1389)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1653)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1662)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1642)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: Unable to load configuration. - [unknown location]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:58)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:374)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:418)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: Unable to locate parent package [showcase] - [unknown location]
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.getPackageConfig(PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.java:887)
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.buildConfiguration(PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.java:536)
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.buildActionConfigs(PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.java:318)
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.ClasspathPackageProvider.loadPackages(ClasspathPackageProvider.java:53)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:204)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:55)
    ... 17 more
```

Comment: What are you trying to run? Under what app server? It looks like something is trying to reference the "showcase" package, which isn't defined. More details are required.

Comment: @Awadhesh still you are using FilterDispatcher it's obsolete. Use StrutsPrepareAndExecute instead of that.

Answer (score 2):

This problem occurs just because you missed some struts library files. Please make sure that all your library files are included in the build path.

Answer (score 0):

From the error console it appears clearly that struts2 is unable to load configuration files as manager is unable to resolve the path.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed to add the struts2 jar ...you may add struts2-core-2.1.8.jar and then use org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
in the configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem in windows with Intellij IDE.I am using tomcat server. I copied all the jars of Struts2

```
asm.jar
asm-commons.jar
asm-tree.jar
commons-fileupload.jar
commons-io.jar
commons-lang.jar
freemarker.jar
javassist.jar
ognl.jar
struts2-core.jar
xwork-core.jar
```

to `F:\xampp\tomcat\lib` folder  and it works.

Answer (score 0):

The exception trace means your app is trying to find struts2-core.jar which it is not getting on the classpath. Add the library and other dependencies along with it. If you have already added, please make sure that it is available at the server (deployment assembly in case of eclipse/ lib folder in WEB-INF)

If you are trying to build a new webapp, it is advisable to avoid adding the jars manually and rather use a build tool like apache or gradle take care of it.
The process is a lot more simpler and conventional. 
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.struts/

You could also try using readymade archetypes to avoid startup errors of all sorts. You can refer to the following link for later:
https://struts.apache.org/docs/struts-2-maven-archetypes.html

Answer (score 0):

Missing JARs and duplicate JARs are the main reason. I would prefer to follow these steps for a Struts2 MVC Application:

1. Create Dynamic Web Application project in Eclipse (or equivalent in your IDE)
2. Add all the required JAR files into your build path and your WEB-INF/lib folder (or appropriate folders as needed by your server). I had used Eclipse Mars + Tomcat 8
3. Add filter tags to your web.xml to redirect all URLs to the StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter (that's the latest for struts2)

   ```
     org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
   ```
4. Create necessary view pages
5. Create necessary Action class by either extending ActionSupport class or implementing Action interface (I would prefer the former!)
6. Create struts.xml and place it in your SRC folder of your context root *i.e project folder root level. Place all your action-to-result mappings inside this xml file.
7. Double check all files to make sure all spellings are spelled correctly.

Note: These are general steps for a normal study-level Struts2 assignment. Actual production code may vary.